# Куда сохраняется промежуточные значения assembler?

Tags: ассемблер, intel

Работа ведется с ассемблером i8080. У него есть такая команда как CPI d8. Данная команда выполняет операцию сравнения с непосредственными данными. Сравнение происходит путем вычитания задаваемого значения из значения регистра аккумулятора A. И в зависимости от полученного промежуточного значения выставляется флаг. Возможно, неправильно описал весь процесс, но вопрос заключается в том, где сохраняется это промежуточное значение? Сохраняется ли оно вообще? Можно ли с ним как-то взаимодействовать?

Comment: При просто сравнении результат сравнения никуда не сохраняется, просто флаги выставляются. Если нужно это промежуточное значение - просто используйте вычитание вместо сравнения.